# Water pad for humidifier-can I buy larger and cut it to the size of my humidifier?

Tags: humidifier, wet

I have a [Hunter CareFree Plus](https://www.humidifierfilters.com/hunter/37250) (quite old-the thermostat has a analog control -no digital dispaly) and I wanted to start reusing it. It has been in a storage for a while, the filter is quite clogged. We tried the vinegar solution but it did not do much. CLR can't be used with aluminium (I am assuming this filter is made of aluminium)

I am seeing that Lowes has tons of these but different sizes. Assuming that the thickness matches can I cut a bigger one (I still have to figure out how) so it can fit in my humidifier?

I am also seeing some plastic or paper like options for other brands. Since those will be easier to cut, can I use one of those?

Part #3142 sells for a prohibitive price--you can probably buy a brand new humidifier for the same amount.

Comment: Amazon appears to have several Hunter Carefree Plus media replacements.   Model number required to see if there a match tho

Comment: I just added the model above

Comment: it if will fit, it will work, to some extent. might not be as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Hunter model and I have look around for a replacement filter but no one carries them anymore. I ended up buying a filter from Home Depot that looked similar and cut it to size using a hacksaw. As long as you are gentle with the hacksaw blade it seems to work.

The new filter should be the same thickness.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.